# How can I use a list of lists, or a list of sets, for the TfidfVectorizer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, text-classification, tfidfvectorizer

I'm using the *sklearn* **TfidfVectorizer** for text-classification.

I know this vectorizer wants raw text as input, but using a list works (see input1).

However, if I want to use multiple lists (or sets) I get the following *Attribute* error.

Does anyone know how to tackle this problem? Thanks in advance!

```
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words="english")
    input1 = ["This", "is", "a", "test"]
    input2 = [["This", "is", "a", "test"], ["It", "is", "raining", "today"]]

    print(vectorizer.fit_transform(input1)) #works
    print(vectorizer.fit_transform(input2)) #gives Attribute error

input 1:
  (3, 0)    1.0

input 2:
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py",
>   line 1381, in fit_transform
>       X = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).fit_transform(raw_documents)   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py",
>   line 869, in fit_transform
>       self.fixed_vocabulary_)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py",
>   line 792, in _count_vocab
>       for feature in analyze(doc):   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py",
>   line 266, in 
>       tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py",
>   line 232, in 
>       return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower()) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Answer (score 8):

*Note that input1 works, but it considers each element of the list (string) as a different document to vectorize.*

In the case of input2, I assume you want to vectorize each "sentence" (sublists).  One solution is using the following list comprehension syntax:

```
input2_corrected = [" ".join(x) for x in input2]
```

which produces

```
['This is a test', 'It is raining today']
```

which does not yield the AttributeError anymore.

Comment: Do you know how to do the same if `input2` is a dataframe and I want to apply this in every row of the dataframe?

Comment: ["slight", "problem", "might be", "with spaces"]...

Answer (score 0):

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words="english")

input1 = ["This", "is", "a", "test"]
input2 = [["This", "is", "a", "test"], ["It", "is", "raining", "today"]]

vectorizer.fit(input1)

input1_vec = vectorizer.transform(input1)
input2_vec = vectorizer.transform(input2)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).