# Apply TfidfVectorizer in every row of dataframe that is a list of lists

Tags: python, list, dataframe, tfidfvectorizer

I have a pandas dataframe containing 2 columns and I want to use `sklearn TfidfVectorizer` for **text-classification** in one of them. However this column is a list of lists and TFIDF wants raw input as text. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633153/how-can-i-use-a-list-of-lists-or-a-list-of-sets-for-the-tfidfvectorizer?rq=1) they provide a solution in case we have just one list of lists, but I would like to ask how it would be possible to apply this function in every single row of my dataframe, which row contains a list of lists. Thank you in advance.

```html
Input:

0    [[this, is, the], [first, row], [of, dataframe]]
1    [[that, is, the], [second], [row, of, dataframe]]
2    [[etc], [etc, etc]]
```

Wanted Output:

```
0    ['this is the', 'first row', 'of dataframe']
1    ['that is the', 'second', 'row of dataframe']
2    ['etc', 'etc etc']
```

Comment: Could you add some sample input?

Comment: I updated the question Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[[['this', 'is', 'the'], ['first', 'row'], ['of', 'dataframe']]],
                        [[['that', 'is', 'the'], ['second'], ['row', 'of', 'dataframe']]]],
                  columns=['paragraphs'])


df['result'] = df['paragraphs'].apply(lambda xs: [' '.join(x) for x in xs])
print(df['result'])
```

**Output**

```
0     [this is the, first row, of dataframe]
1    [that is the, second, row of dataframe]
Name: result, dtype: object
```

Further, if you want to apply the vectorizer in conjunction with the above function you could do something like this:

```
def vectorize(xs, vectorizer=TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words="english")):
    text = [' '.join(x) for x in xs]
    return vectorizer.fit_transform(text)


df['vectors'] = df['paragraphs'].apply(vectorize)
print(df['vectors'].values)
```

Comment: Is this result normal?

`[<10x17 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'`

` with 19 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>`

 `<644x855 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'`

`with 3092 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>`

Comment: @joasa That is because vectorizer.fit_transform returns a sparse matrix, by applying it to each cell you get a column of sparse matrices.